# Is the spelling fundraising, fund-raising or fund raising?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, hyphenation, variants

I have seen different spellings for *fundraising* and would like to know the current best practice. The history of this word/phrase is also of interest to me.

Comment: I think the etymology of this word is rather obvious: started off as two words, *fund raising*, and then, over time, people used it enough that it became one word, *fundraising*. As with almost all hyphenation-versus-one-word questions, it is completely optional whether you hyphenate or not.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I don't think it is correct to call English or any other language "obvious". Even the very strict formal languages used in computer programming have to be documented with detailed grammars to ensure they are correctly implemented. For example, both Merriam-Webster and Oxford dictionaries spell "ice cream" as two words despite its huge popularity. And as Sven Yargs has shown, these choices can change over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Books' Ngram Viewer has some severe limitations in its ability to track hyphenated words—but in the case of *fund raising* vs. *fund-raising* vs. *fundraising*, Ngram's bad behavior actually helps underscore the dominance of the spelling *fundraising* in current usage.

Because the Ngram algorithm treats instances of *fund-raising* as though the word were spelled as two separate word with no hyphen (*fund raising*), an Ngram chart that tracks *fund raising* (blue line) versus *fundraising* (red line) is actually tracking the relative frequency of *fund raising* and *fund-raising* against that of *fundraising*. Here is the Ngram chart for the period 1930–2008:

[image]

The chart indicates that from the late 1930s (when the terms began to be used with some degree of frequency) until the mid-1980s, the popularity of *fund raising* and *fund-raising* (considered together) exceeded the popularity of *fundraising* (considered by itself); but from the early 1990s through the end of the chart (2008), *fundraising* has been considerably more popular than the other two combined.

The treatment of the term in Merriam-Webster's *Collegiate Dictionary* series is far more conservative than I would have expected, given the Ngram data. Through the *Eighth Collegiate* (1973), there is no entry for the term—not because the term didn't exist, but because the dictionary viewed it as consisting of two separate words (*fund* and *raising*) that did not possess any special, otherwise uninferable meaning as a compound expression.

The *Ninth Collegiate* (1983) breaks with its predecessors by including an entry for *fund-raising* (with a hyphen) as a noun and dating the word to 1940. That is not surprising. But the *Tenth Collegiate* (1993), the *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003), and even the [current online Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fundraising) persist in spelling *fund-raising* as a hyphenated word. It seems quite clear to me that actual usage has left MW behind.

Far more in tune with the times is *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, which went from having no entry for the term in its 1980 edition to including a listing for *fundraising* or *fund-raising* in its third edition (1992) to dropping the hyphenated form altogether in its fifth edition (2011).

Publishers that base their spelling decisions on guidance from Merriam-Webster will either insist on the spelling *fund-raising* or will include *fundraising* in its in-house style guide as an explicit overruling of MW's spelling preference. Publishers that follow *AHDEL* (a number that is growing as American Heritage continues to publish new editions of its print dictionary every ten years or so, while Merriam-Webster hasn't published a new print dictionary since 2003) will use *fundraising*.

If you aren't required to follow an established house style, you're free to choose the spelling/ punctuation style you prefer, but it seems clear that *fundraising* is rapidly eclipsing its rivals in the publishing world at large.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Ngram Viewer - it's a brilliant resource! Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Canada and we follow the British style of spelling. My Oxford dictionary has this listed as 'fund-raising'.